# how to get the column name containing a string in a mysql row

Tags: php, mysql

I have SELECTED a particular ROW in the table using the SELECT statement. In this row, I want to find the column that contains a particular string.

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5
A    |  B   |   D  |   E  |   G
```

I want to know which column contains the string E. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
select (case when col1 = 'E' then 'col1'
             when col2 = 'E' then 'col2'
             when col3 = 'E' then 'col3'
             when col4 = 'E' then 'col4'
             when col5 = 'E' then 'col5'
        end)
```

If you just want the index:

```
select field('E', col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
```

Comment: ....i want to try the select case option. how do i apply this query to the row. I want to store the name of the column in a variable for use later, e.g $colname='col2';. Kindly help with a code snippet. I am using php with mysql.  thanks.